# Do I need to delete mappings that I don't need anymore?

Tags: gas-limit, mapping

I have a struct like this:

```
    struct Game {

       string gameID;
       string[2] teams;
       string winningTeam;
       string losingTeam;

       mapping(string => uint) totalWeiBet;

       mapping(string => Bet[]) bets;
       mapping(string => Token[]) tokens;
       mapping(string => mapping(address => bool)) wasSuchTokenBet;


       bool isLocked;
       bool isFinalized;
   }
```

and a state mapping which holds all active Games:

```
   mapping(string => Game) activeGames;
```

When I'm done with the game and I no longer need it (because it is finalized) - I am wondering - how much of the struct do I want to delete? Do I simply delete the struct out of active games mapping? Or should I try to clear all the mappings inside of the struct first? Why would I clear them? What if I don't and I simply delete the whole struct? Does delete cost me additional gas in any case, or it's the other way around - it never costs anything so there is no disadventage of deleting?

Thanks for help again! I love the community here!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the struct you have to pay gas.

In my opinion this is a better way to manage structs. You just push the new struct in an array and leave the old ones that you dont need anymore.

```
Game[] public games;
```

struct Game{

```
   string gameID;
   string[2] teams;
   string winningTeam;
   string losingTeam;

   mapping(string => uint) totalWeiBet;

   mapping(string => Bet[]) bets;
   mapping(string => Token[]) tokens;
   mapping(string => mapping(address => bool)) wasSuchTokenBet;


   bool isLocked;
   bool isFinalized;
```

}

Comment: Not possible in my case because I need to map games with corresponding ID and doesn't anwser my questions. Thanks for help though.